# Redux connect - Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I'm receiving this error `Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module` after starting a new project and implementing redux and react-navigation.

The debugger steps through the initialization of my code but I cannot see where a more descriptive error is thrown. The only thing I see is that there is indeed no method called `runApplication` while debugging. My setup is different from the default AppRegistry because of `react-redux`.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './store';
import AppReducer from './reducers';
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist'
import AppWithNavigationState from './navigator'

export default class App extends React.Component {
    store = configureStore(AppReducer);

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        persistStore(this.store).purge();
    }

    render() {
        return <Provider store={this.store}>
            <AppWithNavigationState />
        </Provider>
    }
}
```

As far as my understanding goes, there is no need to register my App-class and no need for manually registering my component using the `AppRegistry`. I get a feeling my code is to blame because this used to work before, but the stacktrace doesn't point to anything.

Of course, when adding `AppRegistery.registerComponent`, it works! But that doesn't explain to me why this wasn't necessary before.

My `AppNavigator` class:

```
import React from 'react'
import {
    BackHandler,
} from 'react-native'
import {
    addNavigationHelpers,
    StackNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import Start from './components/start'
import Login from './components/login'
import AppCamera from './components/camera'

export const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
    Start: {
        screen: Start,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'App',
        },
    },
    Login: {
        screen: Login,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Login',
        }
    },
    Camera: {
        screen: AppCamera,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Camera',
        }
    }

}, {
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: 'none',
});

// const AppWithNavigationState = ({ dispatch, nav }) => (
//     <AppNavigator navigation={addNavigationHelpers({ dispatch, state: nav })} />
// );

export class AppWithNavigationState extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', function() {
            const { dispatch, navigation, nav } = this.props;
            if (nav.routes.length === 1 && (nav.routes[0].routeName === 'Login' || nav.routes[0].routeName === 'Start')) {
                return false;
            }
            // if (shouldCloseApp(nav)) return false
            dispatch({ type: 'Navigation/BACK' });
            return true;
        }.bind(this));
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress');
    }

    render() {
        return <AppNavigator navigation={addNavigationHelpers({ dispatch: this.props.dispatch, state: this.props.nav })} />
    }
}

AppWithNavigationState.propTypes = {
    dispatch: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    nav: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    auth: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    nav: state.nav,
    auth: state.auth,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AppWithNavigationState);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just kill all node process and start npm server and run application:

Step1: run command killall -9 node

Step2: run command npm start

Step3: run command react-native run-ios OR react-native run-android